# How to set INT variable from expression in MySql Procedure?

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE all(bagName Varchar(50), bagType Varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE valId INT;

SET valId = (
select c.bid from catalog c where (c.name = @bagName AND c.abbr = @bagType)
);
select valId;
END $$

call all("Kickers", "Kr");
```

The above query results in valId value being null. However data is there. Why is it showing null?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `bagName` and `@bagName` are not the same variable. The variables with the `@` sigil are user-defined session variables. The variables without `@` are procedure arguments or else local variables created inside the procedure with `DECLARE`.

You don't have to declare user-defined variables, you can just use them and they are created automatically, but their default value is NULL. This is what your code example does. They don't inherit the value of the variable that seems to have a similar name without the `@`.

It's recommended to declare the procedure parameters with `IN`, `OUT`, or `INOUT` to be clear how they will be used.

Also it's recommended to use `SELECT ... INTO` to assign a value to a local variable.

So I would write your procedure as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE all(IN bagName VARCHAR(50), IN bagType VARCHAR(50))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE valId INT;

  SELECT c.bid FROM catalog c 
  WHERE c.name = bagName AND c.abbr = bagType
  INTO valId;

  SELECT valId;
END $$

CALL all('Kickers', 'Kr');
```